# Modifying the column and vertical spacing in a tabular environment

Tags: tables

I saw that the default separation between columns in a tabular environment is `6pt`. In the display rendered from the following code, such a column spacing is a bit tight. How would I use `\hskip` or `\tabcolsep` to triple this default value? How would I increase the vertical spacing between the rows by `3pt`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{8.) }Compute the following function values. \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hphantom{\textbf{8.) }}\hspace*{1em}
\begin{tabular}{r@{\textbf{ }}lr@{\textbf{ }}l}
\textbf{a.)}    &   $\lfloor 1.1 \rfloor$   &   \textbf{b.)}    &   $\lceil 1.1 \rceil$ \\
\textbf{c.)}    &   $\lfloor -0.1 \rfloor$  &   \textbf{d.)}    &   $\lceil -0.1 \rceil$ \\
\textbf{e.)}    &   $\lceil 2.99 \rceil$    &   \textbf{f.)}    &   $\lceil -2.99 \rceil$ \\
\textbf{g.)}    &   $\big\lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil \big\rfloor$
&
\textbf{h.)}    &   $\big\lceil \lfloor \frac{1}{2} \rfloor + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil + \frac{1}{2} \big\rceil$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the horizontal part: Just use `\bgroup\tabcolsep=3\tabcolsep` prior to your `tabular` environment and `\egroup` afterwards. The `\bgroup...\egroup` keeps the changes local.

Comment: Depending on the font size that's in use, 18pt will be somewhere between `\quad` and `\qquad`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in my comment, for the horizontal part use `\tabcolsep=3\tabcolsep`.
For the vertical spacing you can use `\extrarowheight` which is introduced by
the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{8.) }Compute the following function values. \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hphantom{\textbf{8.) }}\hspace*{1em}
\bgroup\tabcolsep=3\tabcolsep
\extrarowheight=3pt
\begin{tabular}{r@{\textbf{ }}lr@{\textbf{ }}l}
\textbf{a.)}    &   $\lfloor 1.1 \rfloor$   &   \textbf{b.)}    &   $\lceil 1.1 \rceil$ \\
\textbf{c.)}    &   $\lfloor -0.1 \rfloor$  &   \textbf{d.)}    &   $\lceil -0.1 \rceil$ \\
\textbf{e.)}    &   $\lceil 2.99 \rceil$    &   \textbf{f.)}    &   $\lceil -2.99 \rceil$ \\
\textbf{g.)}    &   $\big\lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil \big\rfloor$
&
\textbf{h.)}    &   $\big\lceil \lfloor \frac{1}{2} \rfloor + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil + \frac{1}{2} \big\rceil$
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

How I would create your content:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\multicolsep=1.25mm

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[
    ,label=\textbf{\arabic*.)}
    ,itemsep=\bigskipamount
    ,align=left
    ,labelsep=1em
    ,labelwidth=1em
    ,labelindent=0pt
    ,leftmargin=!
  ]
  \item Compute the following function values.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)},itemsep=3pt]
        \item $\lfloor 1.1 \rfloor$
        \item $\lfloor -0.1 \rfloor$
        \item $\lceil 2.99 \rceil$
        \item $\big\lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil \big\rfloor$
        \item $\lceil 1.1 \rceil$
        \item $\lceil -0.1 \rceil$
        \item $\lceil -2.99 \rceil$
        \item $\big\lceil \lfloor \frac{1}{2} \rfloor + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil + \frac{1}{2} \big\rceil$
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
  \item Draw a circle.
  \item Rethink your choice to use a \texttt{tabular} environment.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did add `\begingroup` before `\tabcolsep=8\tabcolsep`, which is before the `tabular` environment, and `\endgroup` after the `tabular` environment as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

Decluttering your code should be an important objective. In the following, two new column types are defined: one for automatic bold-facing, the other for automatic math mode. The result is much more readable code in the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}     % automatic math mode
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\bfseries}l} % automatic bold face

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\textbf{8.)} Compute the following function values. 
\par\smallskip\noindent%
\begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.33} % less cramped look
\hspace*{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{}BL@{\qquad}BL@{}}
a.) & \lfloor  1.1 \rfloor  &  b.) & \lceil  1.1 \rceil \\
c.) & \lfloor -0.1 \rfloor  &  d.) & \lceil -0.1 \rceil \\
e.) & \lceil  2.99 \rceil   &  f.) & \lceil-2.99 \rceil \\
g.) & \bigl\lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil \bigr\rfloor &
h.) & \bigl\lceil \lfloor \frac{1}{2} \rfloor + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil 
      + \frac{1}{2} \bigr\rceil \\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a custom `enumerate` environment, with the help of `enumitem` and the `tasks`  environment for the horizontal list rather than `tabular`. This way, all labels  will be automatically calculated and formatted, and will be referable.

In addition, I defined a `\Floor` and a `\Ceil` commands which can adapt their size  in their starred version. You can see them at work in the last item.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*.), font = \bfseries, start = 8, wide = 0pt, widest=\textbf{0.)},leftmargin =* ]
\item Compute the following function values. \vskip1.25mm%\
\begin{tasks}[counter-format = tsk[a].), label-format = \bfseries, label-width = 1.5em](3)%{r@{\textbf{ }}lr@{\textbf{ }}l}
\task $\lfloor 1.1 \rfloor$
\task $\lceil 1.1 \rceil$
\task $\lfloor -0.1 \rfloor$
\task $\lceil -0.1 \rceil$
\task $\lceil 2.99 \rceil$
\task $\lceil -2.99 \rceil$
\task $\bigl\lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil \bigr\rfloor$
\task $\Ceil*{\Floor*{ \frac{1}{2}} + \Ceil*{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}}$
\end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]